# How to reduce the size of electron angular app

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, electron

I am trying to design an angular app for windows and Linux platforms. I am using the electron framework. I just built a simple app that displays the angular home page. The size of this app is around 250MB. This is too large. If anyone has developed an electron-angular app. Can you mention the size of your app. And any tips on how to reduce the size of the application.
Note: Angular app is compiled to /dist, its size is just 250KB but when the whole app is built is 250MB!

** main.js**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

let win;

console.log(__dirname);
function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 600, 
    height: 600,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    icon: `file://${__dirname}/dist/Angular-electron/favicon.ico`
  })


  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/dist//Angular-electron/index.html`)

  //// uncomment below to open the DevTools.
  // win.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Event when the window is closed.
  win.on('closed', function () {
    win = null
  })
}

// Create window on electron intialization
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {

  // On macOS specific close process
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  // macOS specific close process
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

Below is the root component.

**app.component.html**

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Angular-electron';
 
}
```

This is the package.json script, I build the angular and simultaneously build electron as shown below
Note: I use the electron-packager to build the app for production.

```
"builderForWindows": "ng build --prod && electron-packager ./dist --out winx64 --overwrite --platform win32 "
```

Below is the screenshot of the application.
[image]

Comment: Please let me know If more detail is needed on the question :)

Comment: I may be mistaken but the 250mb also includes chromium and node.js bundled in.

Comment: Electon apps include the whole angular distro and node.js and chromium! The size of your dist is just a tiny percentage of the actual output. If you want a small footprint electron probably isn't for you.

Answer (score 1):

When you build your app for Electron, it adds all your dependencies in `dependencies` section of `package.json`

Try to move all your angular dependencies in `devDependencies` section of `package.json`

This should reduce the size of your final package.

Otherwise you should have a look at [electron-builder](https://www.electron.build/) and start building your app as a Linux/MacOS/Windows package.

For example, my [electron-angular](https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron) project generate a 45Mo Windows executable.

Comment: I used your git project as scaffold and it worked like a charm, thanks. I copied/pasted my `dependencies` and `devDependencies` from my original project to your scaffold, then my code to `src`, fixed what hat to be fixed and voilá, from 950MB to 230MB (for MacOS). I cannot find the reason why, could you give me a hint? I'd like to understand and learn.

Comment: It's because Angular dependencies are added in the final bundle when defined as `dependencies` instead of `devDependencies`